# Enter while typing in the mod flag reason should send the flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, user-experience

We know comments use minimarkdown, which discards newlines. Thus, [the Enter key submits the comment instead](/q/63303).

Flag messages also discard newlines. The Enter key, however, inserts one instead of submitting the flag.

I agree that this might trigger angry flames from the people who hate the comments behaviour suddenly starting to submit partial flag messages (although I only have ever seen one or two flag messages that might've used one.) However, that's how it should work.

For <s>consistency</s> science.

<sub>You monster.</sub>

Comment: Comments are editable later, but flag reason is not.

Comment: I was going to agree with badp but seeing @YOU's comment made me think again. It's not a bad idea, but could cause more problems than it solves.

Comment: @Chris How often do you _need_ (or hell, have you _seen_) a newline in a flag to begin with?

Comment: @badp - I wasn't thinking of actually needing a newline, but of not being able to edit it. Having the extra click gives you a chance to review what you've typed.

Comment: @ChrisF: I was going to disagree with badp, but then, flag messages are typically very short, with a low risk of hitting the Enter key by mistake. If your flags are so long hitting Enter too soon is a real risk, maybe they're too long?

Comment: @Giles - that should be true. H'mm amazing how something apparently so simple can be more complex the more you look at it.

Comment: @YOU Comments are editable only for a short time period.

Comment: [Disable enter key for flag submission](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203877/997587) marked status-completed in 2020