# Pressing <enter> in flagging/closing modal should submit the form

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Enter while typing in the mod flag reason should send the flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89361/enter-while-typing-in-the-mod-flag-reason-should-send-the-flag)

I vote to flag/close a lot of questions, and thus am in the [flagging/closing modal dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJE5b.png) a lot. I also prefer using the keyboard over copious mouse movement whenever possible.

It would be wonderful if pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> while in the modal dialog (even if only after selecting one of the radio options) would submit the form, instead of requiring a slow mouse movement.

There is a [similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89361/enter-while-typing-in-the-mod-flag-reason-should-send-the-flag) about enabling this functionality when typing in a text box in the dialog, but that's not what I'm concerned with here—I'd like <kbd>Enter</kbd> to have an effect when outside of a text box, which it currently doesn't.

Comment: While you are trying to reach the button with your mouse, you have some extra seconds to reconsider the flag/close vote! :P

Comment: @animuson That is not a duplicate of this, that question is specific to when the focus is in the "reason" text box, while this is not about that.

Comment: Don't really understand why this was closed as a duplicate. I don't want the feature that's in that question, and it's *related* but *different*.

Comment: While I don't really see any use in this feature, I agree it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I feel it is *close enough* to not warrant cluttering the site with a slight variation of the question. Hitting enter in the dialogue box does not have the desired effect (in the text area it adds a newline, in the rest it is ignored).