# Disable enter key for flag submission

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, usability, keyboard-shortcuts

I've just tried to flag a question as duplicate. As there was a delay between me typing in my search to find the correct question, and the results showing, I hit enter. (Presuming this was required to submit search.) Instead, I saw the 'Thanks for flagging' box - it appears that a random question was selected as my 'duplicate'. (I'd imagine it's more likely that the results appeared a millisecond before my enter click registered, and the first was selected or something - but I don't really want to submit incorrect flags all over the place to test this out!)

My issue now is, I have no way of correcting my error. I can see three potential solutions:

1. Allow the removal of mis-clicked flags. (Apparently not possible, cite: [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87500/cancel-misclicked-flags).)
2. Provide a way for a user to edit a submitted, active flag.
3. Disable the enter-key-to-submit on this form. (Which I've no doubt will shortly encounter all sorts of cries against usability!)

As to which the best solution is, I'll leave to debate. My issue now however is, that I am a) going to have a black mark against my name for an incorrect flag I had no intention of submitting. and b) have no method of resubmitting a correct flag, to deal with the duplicate question issue I was first intending of tackling!

Interested to see what people think, I appreciate this is an edge-case, but then there seems a relatively easy solution.

Comment: *"a) going to have a black mark against my name for an incorrect flag I had no intention of submitting."* <-- Don't worry too much about it. No-one is perfect, and I would be very surprised if anyone would hold it against you unless you made a habit of it. As for the suggestion: In essence it is default browser behaviour. I am not sure if I would like the change, but I probably wouldn't miss it.

Comment: Incidentally, my flag has now been marked as 'helpful' (I'll presume by some kind soul who came across this post.) However - the question doesn't show the duplicate notice - and I'm still unable to submit a second duplicate flag for the actual duplicate question.

Comment: Just add a comment with "Possible duplicate: " and the link to the duplicate question. If someone agrees with you they will cast a close-vote on it and/or flag it (too). In the worst case only the OP will read it ;-)

Comment: A potential option yes, but more of a workaround - what about the many non-contributor Googlers, who might follow a bit "Duplicate Question" banner at the top, but likely won't read through the comments section. 

On another note, my incorrect flag, has been accepted now, and the question not shows a bit "Duplicate" banner at the top, linking to a question it really isn't a dup of!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed).

Pressing `Enter` now goes to a new line. You will have to manually click `Flag Question` or `Flag Answer` to actually flag the post.